# ReactJS - Dynamic State

Tags: reactjs

How do I dynamically create the state so I can assign 'open'/'close' based on front-end requirements?

E.g.
I have a table with rows in which I have a `Fab` component. That component has to set a unique ID to open/close to handle the animation. I do not know how many of these rows I will have so I can't pre-populate the state with `active1`, `active2` etc.

Code Example (In this example I am passing 'active1', 'active2' with the object manually, but realistically that isn't a real approach I feel.

```
{Object.keys(characters).map((k, i) => {
<Fab 
    active= // how do I specify the state of 'this' instance?
    direction="left"
    containerStyle={{}}
    style={{
              backgroundColor: "#5067FF"
          }}
    position="topRight"
    onPress={() => this.setState({ //how so I specify 'this' instances state? })}>
...redacted
```

I've tried to add a sample similar to my code. Let's say I am passing in 5 `Users` and each `User` should have this Fab. At this point my state is blank so I have tried implementing a `for each` loop into `componentdidmount` to populate the state, this worked, but I had two issues based on how I managed state.

A) All fabs were open, always.
B) No fabs would ever open.

This is because of my `onPress` not updating the correct state.

I feel like I have to be way over-complicating this issue and I am tearing up my code to get it to work, so I figured I'd come here to ask.

Let me know what other code I can share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way of achieving this is to keep an `activeArray` in `state`,
which you can toggle activeness of an element buy pushing or removing the element (or just its `id` or some property which is unique) from `activeArray`.

So there should be a function on `onPress` like:

```
handlePress = (k) => {
    if(this.state.activeArray.indexOf(k) > -1){
        // remove element
        // for example: 
        this.setState(state => ({activeArray: state.activeArray.filter(activeElement => activeElement !== k)}))
    } else {
        // push element
        // for example: 
        this.setState(state => ({activeArray: [...state.activeArray, k]}))
    }
}
```

Then for `Fab` component:

```
<Fab 
  active={this.state.activeArray.indexOf(k) > -1}
  direction="left"
  containerStyle={{}}
  style={{
          backgroundColor: "#5067FF"
  }}
  position="topRight"
  onPress={() => this.handlePress(k)}>
```

This line:

```
 active={this.state.activeArray.indexOf(k) > -1}
```

means if `k` is inside `activeArray` then `active` is `true`.

Comment: I like this solution, but I seem to be a bit confused. Essentially instead of true/false you add/remove from state to create the same open/close logic?

I ask confused because it is not closing when I try this method.

Comment: I put a console log inside of the `if/else` of `handlePress()` and else is -always- triggering, which is causing the Fab not opening. Thoughts on cause?

Comment: I forced the if to trigger and get a comp error on click. `state.filter is not a function`

Comment: My bad, `this.state` should've been `this.state.activeArray`, I updated the answer.

Comment: No worries; I actually thought it was that also so I modified it myself. No longer get an error but obviously nothing is pushed to the state. I have to assume it's because there is nothing ever defined as 'activeElement' - What exactly is that referencing? Since 'k' is technically the element.

Comment: `activeElement` is arg passed to `filter` function

Comment: And for initial state you need to add `activeArray:[] `

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171544/discussion-between-dnorthrup-and-kiarashws).

Answer (score 1):

You can set the dynamic state using JSON bracket ([]) notation.

```
{
   Object.keys(characters).map((k, i) => {
     let dynamicStateName = "active"+i //it will set the dynamicStateName as active with index. ie, active1, active2 and so on
     return(
       { this.state[dynamicStateName] !== false || this.state[dynamicStateName] !== undefined  ? 

       (<Fab 
         active= {dynamicStateName}// specify the state of 'this' instance here as dynamicStateName
         direction="left"
         containerStyle={{}}
         style={{
              backgroundColor: "#5067FF"
         }}
         position="topRight"
         onPress={() => {(this.state[dynamicStateName] != undefined) ? (this.state[dynamicStateName] ? this.setState({ [dynamicStateName]: false }) : this.setState({ [dynamicStateName]: true })) : this.setState({ [dynamicStateName]: true })}  } />  // it will set the state as true if undefined. It will act as toggleable
         ):
         ( <button onPress={() => this.setState({ [dynamicStateName]: true })}>OpenFabButton<button>
           // initially the dynamicState will be either undefined or false. At that time the button will be show. On clicking the button it will enable the fab component
         )
     )
  })
}
```

This will fix yours

Comment: This actually seems to be close to what I need, but it doesn't close using the `onPress()` logic applied.

Comment: Do you need to close the particular fab component onPress

Comment: Yea, it should always close 'this' Fab.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Kindly check that, whether it fits your need